# Movie about a cursed place where people die in bizarre accidents

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

To my recollection, this movie seemed to follow the archetypal "Cabin in the Woods" format, so I would guess that it is American. Basically, a group of characters go vacationing to some place. Along the way they are warned by a sheriff that the place is cursed, and they will all die. The characters are killed off in bizarre ways. For instance, one of the characters is standing in front of a woodchipper. Another character tries to lunge at him while the aforementioned character casually steps out of the way. Thus, the character that tried to lunge at him ends up diving headfirst into the woodchipper. The sheriff shows up later and the characters try to explain the bizarre deaths, but he does not believe them, then tells the characters that he warned them.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the accepted answer indicates that the Story-ID was not about science fiction or fantasy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of the accident with the woodchipper reminded me of *Tucker & Dale vs. Evil.*

It has a strong 'cabin in the woods' vibe as well as a serious of increasingly unlikely deaths.

***Warning. NSFW Scenes.***

At one point they encounter a sheriff and try to explain what happened.

Comment: Notably, if this is the correct answer then there's not any fantasy content in it.